# Swift - computed properties vs database operation

Tags: swift

I am very new to protocol-oriented programming in swift. I am working on an OTT product with a download SDK. I have several things in my code.

1. `VODContent` -> Model which represents the vod.
2. `OfflineMedia` -> a protocol.
3. `RLMOfflineMedia` -> a realm database class to
   store VOD data inside SDK.

I have confirmed both `VODContent` and  `RLMOfflineMedia` to protocol `OfflineMedia`. So that I can use `OfflineMedia` as an adaptor in-between  `VODContent` and `RLMOfflineMedia`. Inside SDK I have created an `extension` for  `OfflineMedia` to perform database operations. It has a similar structure as follows.

```
//RLMOfflineMedia+OfflineMedia.swift
//which handles the DB operations related to RLMOfflineMedia

extension  OfflineMedia {
 var realmObject: RLMOfflineMedia {
  return //check for an existing entry in database using primary key or  creates a new realm object and return it.
 }
}
```

Here inside SDK, I can easily manage database operations quickly using 'OfflineMedia.realmObject' or `self as? RLMOfflineMedia`. Everything is working perfectly at this point. But later I realize, whenever I use `OfflineMedia.realmObject` it will perform a database operation that is relatively heavy. As a good programmer, I am supposed to avoid this kind of situation. I need to know what is the best solution to this problem. I, myself have some ideas but I am not sure those are the right ones. Just mentioning them below.

- Add a stored property inside `VODContent` and `OfflineMedia` (with a
  setter). Store fetched object inside this and later before performing database operation check whether this object is nil or not. (Sounds
  like a nasty solution)
- Create an array or set to use as a database cache.

Note: I am assuming that the database itself has no caching mechanism that avoids fetching the same thing again and again.

As of now, I kept my old implementation which is less optimized. I am waiting for an answer so that I can optimize the code.

**Update:- **
Adding more info about `VODContent`, `OfflineMedia`, and `RLMOfflineMedia`

Here `VODContent` represents an object from the server, parsed into a swift object. `OfflineMedia` is a protocol used as a bridge to connect `VODContent` to the SDK. By confirming `VODContent` to `OfflineMedia`, I am able to get whatever properties need to save/process data in my SDK. That means I am not passing video assets as a `VODContent` object, instead, it's an `OfflineMedia` (I think this is called dependency injection). Here I am using `OfflineContent` as a mediator. Inside SDK `OfflineMedia` represents a `VODContent` and I can save it to DB by confirming `RLMOfflineMedia` class to `OfflineMedia`. I have created several extensions for `OfflineMedia` to perform different operations (eg: DB operations, download video asset, etc), simply most of the business logic is written inside `OfflineMedia` extension.

Comment: I think you're letting your DB get way too close to your real code. The `OfflineMedia` shouldn't know anything about Realm. How are these types being used?

Comment: almost every DB operations are managed in OfflineMedia's extension. I have created different files for different purposes. @Alexander-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Can you elaborate some more? If the job of `OfflineMedia` is to abstract over the concretions `VODContent` and `RLMOfflineMedia`, then why does it know about the database, which is a concretion?

Comment: In a file RLMOfflineMedia+OfflineMedia.swift, I have added `extension RLMOfflineMedia: OfflineMedia {}`. It will not expose outside SDK so that `OfflineMedia` doesn't know anything about DB outside SDK. There are multiple files with `OfflineMedia` extensions for various purposes. (Is this a bad implementation? Am I exploiting extensions too much?) @Alexander-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Almost every download operations were performed on top `OfflineMedia`. so that I can perform operations in a fasion `offlineMedia.getDownloadState()` or `offlineMedia.removeFromDB()`. Despite being an adapter `OfflineMedia` has more responsibilities.  Inside SDK `OfflineMedia` is used almost everwhere.

Comment: Could you back up and try to explain each of these types, their purpose, their usage, and the relationships between them?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Updated the question for more clarification